# Wordpress Ecard Plugin - Multiple Email Addresses

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins

I am currently developing a site on Wordpress that is very similar to Hipster Cards. I am using a plugin called WP Ecards which provides the functionality of generating card pages and allowing a user to send a card to someone else via email. The plugin page can be found at this link

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ecards/

The current site that I am working on can be found [here](http://www.cloudfarmstudio.com/OTB), and the page where the ecard is sent from is [here](http://cloudfarmstudio.com/OTB/birthday/happy-birthday-1).

The only functionality that this plugin is missing is that there is no option to send a card to multiple recipients. Does anyone know how I might go about this or would even be able to give me a nudge in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder answer since you didn't show any code and looking it up takes too much time.

You can either define a list of recipient email address fields:

```
<input name="email[]" type="email" value="">
<input name="email[]" type="email" value="">
<input name="email[]" type="email" value="">
```

And then in the PHP plugin iterate over that:

```
foreach ($_POST["email"] as $email) {
    mail($email, ...)
```

Or provide a single address field, where users would have to add a comma-separated list of recpients. In that case you could split it up with e.g.

```
$emails = preg_split("/[,\s]+/", $_POST["email"]);
foreach ($emails ...
```

In practice you might want to add a field each for the recipients name *and* email address.

Answer (score 0):

there is a new wordpress plugin with many features that lately released.
[Mojdeh - WordPress Greeting, eCard, Postcard Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/mojdeh-wordpress-greeting-ecard-postcard-plugin/10103438)